# Is it possible for a User to create a new User bypassing Admin?

Tags: 2010, user

In out organization, We have to create lots of new users in various departments. So, I want Head of Department to create their own users and not approach Admin for same. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: What is HOD?____

Comment: Head of Department

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in my opinion it is not, unless you are using Form Based Authentication.

In FBA, you could even have people themselves create their own users: anonymous user clicks Register, fills in a form with some essential information, a working e-mail address, and that's it. Basically, like you register yourself on most of the websites on the WWW.

But if you are using Windows Authentication things are not that simple (at least from this point of view they are a little more complicated). Windows Authentication makes, most of the time, authentication of users smooth, because the users are already created in Active Directory. They are not created in Sharepoint, just added to different security groups of Sharepoint. The creation of users is handled by the guys who are administering the AD. And it's pretty unlikely that the same rights would be given to any Head Of Department.

What could be done, to ease a little the job of AD admins and of HOD, to implement a workflow (why not in Sharepoint), which would be initiated by the HOD, who fills in all the necessary info, and then assigns it to the AD admin, who could create then the user.

**Edit - More explanation on FBA**

FBA is an answer to your problems **only** if the users accessing your Sharepoint site don't need access to other resources too in your company. If they need an AD account anyway to connect to their workstation, to print, to access their mailbox, etc, then an Admin will have to create an AD account for them anyway. Enabling FBA won't solve this problem.

FBA is useful mainly for Internet facing sites or Extranet sites. So if you need to give access to people outside your organization, who will access only your Sharepoint site, then yes, FBA could be a good idea. On this [blogpost](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mahesm/archive/2010/04/07/configure-forms-based-authentication-fba-with-sharepoint-2010.aspx) you wil find a step by step guide on how to enable FBA on your Sharepoint site.

**But be aware:** Enabling FBA involves some major architectural changes in the way authentication is handled on your Sharepoint site, because you need to go from Classic Mode Authentication to Claims Based Authentication. It should well analyzed before you do it, whether you want to do it, whether it will impact other systems which integrate with Sharepoint or custom developed components, whether you should extend your web application and enable FBA on the extension, etc.

I could give you only a general idea on FBA and on the risks involved. The final decision will have to taken inside your company, after reading more blogposts about it and after analyzing all the risks that could appear.

I'm curious what others have to say on this topic :)

Cheers!

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more on how to do it in FBA as I am on it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, @saumilm. Please see my edited answer to your question, above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. FBA is working without any issues on my site. What I need to know is 'How would I let a person of department create its own users?' What will I need to do for same?

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry. I misunderstood your question. You could, for example, create an application page, which would add users to the ASP.Net Membership database in code behind. Example on how to that, can be found [here](http://psterpe.wordpress.com/2009/05/24/adding-users-with-sharepoint-forms-based-authentication/).

Comment: And, if you want to take that idea one step further: deploy that application page as a custom action and put it on the Site Settings page of every site. You could even automate adding the newly created user to an appropriate Site Sharepoint Group (Visitor or Member) at the end of the user creation, in code behind. Then every Head of Department, if they are also administrators of their Sharepoint site, could access that page, create the user and have automatically in the correct Sharepoint Group.

Comment: I am really curious if you found any other solutions for this or will you go for FBA? If you have any other questions about FBA, please let me know. It is an interesting topic. Cheers!

Comment: No, I have not find any solution which is strange!